# Is there a weak homotopy equivalence between $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})/\mathrm{U}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(n)$?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

This question, Is there a weak homotopy equivalence between $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})/\mathrm{U}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(n)$?, is at the end of a long string of my comments in

[Is Sp(2N,$\mathbb{C}$)/U(N) isomorphic to SU(N)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296373/is-sp2n-mathbbc-un-isomorphic-to-sun)

And perhaps the discussion there is useful for this question. I ask this because I don't know how to show this weak homotopy equivalence. I will continue to try to answer this question on my own while I wait for responses but also thought I would just ask with different, more relevant tags.

Comment: The first has cohomological dimension $\dim((2)/())=^2+$ and the second, $n^2−1$

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @Ycor.

Answer (score 4):

No.  $Sp(2N,\mathbb{C})$ 2-connected (you can prove this by induction on $N$; see for instance my answer at [$\mathrm{Sp}(4, \mathbb{C})$ is simply connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930993/mathrmsp4-mathbbc-is-simply-connected) which also works to show it is 2-connected).  So by the long exact sequence in homotopy groups, $\pi_2(Sp(2N,\mathbb{N})/U(N))\cong \pi_1(U(N))\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $\pi_2(SU(N))$ is trivial (which can be proved by induction on $N$ in a similar way) this means they are not weak homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I have a new question, which is, is there an isomorphism between homotopy group $\pi_m(A)$ and homotopy group $\pi_m(B)$, where $A$ is some subgroup or subset of (2,ℂ)/() and B is some subgroup of $SU(n)$.

Comment: @Impossibear This new question is way too vague. No quantifier on $m$. And yes, take a singleton $A$ and $B$ trivial subgroup.

Comment: @Ycor, $m=2$ or $3$, say. And what about nontrivial subgroups, like $S^2$? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Impossibear anyway this is not the right place for asking follow-up questions.

Comment: @Ycor After checking a meta mathexchange post, it seems I should ask a new question and link to this one in this case. I will proceed with that in a few hours unless I hear otherwise.

Comment: Yes. I suggest to ask a precise question, and think about it a little before asking to avoid a trivial answer.